# Convert Mysql Query to Laravel Eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.1

I am using Laravel 5.1 in my application.

My MySQL Query is

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT uu.*,t.left_id AS meb_id,(CAST(t.pair AS UNSIGNED) - IFNULL(p.pair,0)) AS pair FROM (SELECT left_id,
(CASE 
WHEN ((SELECT COUNT(meb_id) FROM user_count WHERE left_id=u.left_id AND active = 1 AND join_date <= '1442255400000') >= (SELECT COUNT(meb_id) FROM user_count WHERE right_id=u.left_id AND active = 1 AND join_date <= '1442255400000')*2) 
THEN (SELECT COUNT(meb_id) FROM user_count WHERE right_id=u.left_id AND active = 1 AND join_date <= '1442255400000')
WHEN ((SELECT COUNT(meb_id) FROM user_count WHERE left_id=u.left_id AND active = 1 AND join_date <= '1442255400000') < (SELECT COUNT(meb_id) FROM user_count WHERE right_id=u.left_id AND active = 1 AND join_date <= '1442255400000')*2) 
THEN ((SELECT COUNT(meb_id) FROM user_count WHERE right_id=u.left_id AND active = 1 AND join_date <= '1442255400000') /2)
WHEN ((SELECT COUNT(meb_id) FROM user_count WHERE right_id=u.left_id AND active = 1 AND join_date <= '1442255400000') >= (SELECT COUNT(meb_id) FROM user_count WHERE left_id=u.left_id AND active = 1 AND join_date <= '1442255400000')*2)
THEN (SELECT COUNT(meb_id) FROM user_count WHERE left_id=u.left_id AND active = 1 AND join_date <= '1442255400000')
WHEN ((SELECT COUNT(meb_id) FROM user_count WHERE right_id=u.left_id AND active = 1 AND join_date <= '1442255400000') < (SELECT COUNT(meb_id) FROM user_count WHERE left_id=u.left_id AND active = 1 AND join_date <= '1442255400000')*2)
THEN ((SELECT COUNT(meb_id) FROM user_count WHERE left_id=u.left_id AND active = 1 AND join_date <= '1442255400000') / 2) END
) AS pair
FROM user_count AS u WHERE  left_id <> 0 GROUP BY left_id) AS t
LEFT JOIN users AS uu ON uu.`id` = t.left_id
LEFT JOIN `total_payment` p ON t.left_id = p.`meb_id`
WHERE t.pair <> 0) AS f WHERE f.pair > 0  AND f.active = 1
```

How Can I convert it in Laravel Eloquent? I don't know how to use `when case` in laravel eloquent.

My Database schema is like this

`user_count` table
[image]

`user` table
[image]

`total_payment` table

[image]

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Not sure I understand why you would want to do this with Eloquent vs using a straight SQL query with the DB facade.

Comment: @Pitchinnate
This query take too much time to execute so i think if i run it using eloquent it would be better.

Comment: I don't think you understand what eloquent is then.

Comment: Eloquent doesn't speed up your database queries. If anything, it likely will add time, as all ORMS have a bit of overhead.
At the low SQL level, Laravel is still sending MySQL the same queries (DBS only understand SQL period), it's still the same SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE. ORM can make for more readable elegant code. Instead of a bunch of long messy queries and string concatenations in your code, you do things like User::all() and then can access attributes like User->name; it's really for readability & portability (no specific sql = portable).

Answer (score 1):

Just surround your raw query with a DB::statement(""), like this :

```
DB::statement("INSERT INTO `mydatabase`.`mytable` (`id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `deleted_at`) VALUES ('7', '2015-09-26 13:38:48', '2015-09-26 13:43:41', NULL)");
```

It will do the job fine and works with seeds as well.

Comment: I am already running this query using `DB::statement("")`.
And i want to run it using `Eloquent`

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent is an ORM (Object-relational mapping), it means you can map your database to PHP objects (Eloquent use the Active Record pattern).

It is not a DBAL however you can still execute SQL queries through the DB Facade.

The example provided by you, the user table can be an Eloquent object.

```
class User extends Model{
   /**
   * The table associated with the model.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  protected $table = 'user';
}
```

Since now you can fetch all user rows like:

```
$userCollection = (new User)->all(); //Fetch all rows
```

Or you can find one by PK like:

```
$user = (new User)->find(123); //123 is the PK of the User
```

Comment: i already run this query using  DB Facade.
But i want to convert this query to Laravel Eloquent.
So how can i do this?
I have created model for each table.