# Convert a Mysql query to Laravel 5 Eloquent?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I am using Laravel 5.1 in my application. My MySQL query is

```
"Select * from "
        . "(Select u.* from "
        . "( "
        . "SELECT u2.id as user_id, u2.fname as fname, u2.lname as lname, u2.uname as uname, u2.email as email, u2.address as address, u2.city_id as city_id, u2.website as website FROM users u1, users u2 where u1.city_id = u2.city_id && u1.id = '$this->current_user_id' ) 
            u left join follows f on u.user_id = f.following_id where f.following_id is null 
            UNION
            Select uu.id as user_id, uu.fname as fname, uu.lname as lname, uu.uname as uname, uu.email as email, uu.address as address, uu.city_id as city_id, uu.website as website from users uu where uu.id in (Select u.user_id from (SELECT user_id FROM reviews group by user_id order by count(user_id) desc5
            ) u left join follows f on u.user_id=f.following_id where f.following_id is null
            )
            ) 
            T LIMIT 5"
```

How can I convert it into Laravel Eloquent?

Comment: did you try converting it?

Comment: desc5?? What's that

Comment: Eloquent is an ORM. So you would need to [create the appropriate models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#defining-models) and [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships).

Answer (score 0):

Is that query functionally identical to this one:

```
SELECT u2.id user_id
     , u2.fname 
     , u2.lname 
     , u2.uname 
     , u2.email 
     , u2.address 
     , u2.city_id 
     , u2.website 
  FROM users u1
  JOIN users u2 
    ON u2.city_id = u1.city_id 
  LEFT
  JOIN follows f 
    ON f.following_id = u.user_id 
 WHERE f.following_id is null 
 UNION
SELECT uu.id user_id
     , uu.fname 
     , uu.lname 
     , uu.uname 
     , uu.email 
     , uu.address 
     , uu.city_id 
     , uu.website 
  FROM users uu
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT r.user_id 
         FROM reviews r
         LEFT
         JOIN follows f
           ON f.following_id = r.user_id 
        WHERE f.following_id IS NULL
        GROUP 
           BY user_id 
        ORDER 
           BY COUNT(user_id) DESC 
        LIMIT 5
     ) x
    ON x.user_id = uu.id;
```

?

Comment: but i want to convert laravel eloquent..?

Comment: Seems like an easier one to convert to me

Comment: Besides, isn't there some kind of DB::raw() functionality

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32738504/convert-mysql-query-to-laravel-eloquent